# Does converting directory to an iso file make it bootable image

Tags: iso

I extracted an ISO file to a directory. Now I want to make that extract files bootable again. Will converting it to .iso make it bootable?

Comment: A bootable ISO isn't a form of *compression* but putting specific information into a set *layout*.

Comment: how will you make iso ? genisoimage, for instance, has many option that might be usefull.

Comment: tar without gzip is not a form of compression too and you need the option x(extract) , to extract the files, so the extract word is not necessary related to compression.

Answer (score 2):

No, but its relatively easy to do that, it depends on how the iso was make bootable in the first instance, you need to have some kind of boot loader like isolinux for example. If there is a directory called isolinux inside it, you have a lucky day! The command that creates the bootable iso will probably look like this:

```
cd thedirectorywithisofiles
mkisofs -o ../your-new.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat \
-no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -V "volume" .
```

So probably is not too hard as you're thinking!

If you think the iso was using grub, you still can ignore it and download and use isolinux as a substitute or try this link: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Making-a-GRUB-bootable-CD_002dROM.html

Comment: "mkisofs command not found" 
installing it says
`Package mkisofs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  genisoimage:i386 genisoimage

E: Package 'mkisofs' has no installation candidate`

Comment: please specify in your question what distribution/OS you are using...some tools might not be available or should be installed

Comment: #apt-get install genisoimage  ?

Comment: i'm using debian jessie